# What's wrong with my code? HTML and CSS Button Type Reset Issue

Tags: html, css

For some reason I have the buttons here all labeled correctly and I've done countless methods of clearing the fields on this form utilizing this, what seems to be simple, button that is supposed to clear the fields when you click on it. I know it's probably something dumb that I'm missing but it'd be great to have a few fresh eyes here.

```css
    body {
      background-color: #f18c8e;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 600px;
      height: 600px;
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 35px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      position: relative;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 10%;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      background-color:rgb(234, 234, 234);
    }
    
    .pid, .cid, .qmin, .qmax, .pmin, .pmax {
      width: 76%;
      font-size: 14px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      background-color: white;  
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02);
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
      margin-top: 2%;
      }
    
    .title {
      font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
      color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
      padding-top: 1em;
      font-size: 100;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    
    .subtitle {
      font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
      color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    
    .search, .clear {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 13px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      margin-top: 6%;
      padding-left: 1em;
      padding-right: 1em;
      width: 30%;
      background-color:cadetblue;
      border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02);
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .clear:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: rgb(81, 139, 141);
    }
    
    .search:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: rgb(81, 139, 141);
    }
    
    .search {
      margin-right: 45px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
    
    <html lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Contact.css"></link>
    
    <head> 
      <title>Wholesale Portal</title>
      <body>
      <div class="container">
        <center>
          <h1 class="title">Wholesale Portal</h1>
          <p class="subtitle">Please enter in values below to begin product search.</p>
          <input type="text" class="pid"  placeholder="Product Name"></input>
          <input type="text" class="cid" placeholder="Warehouse City"></input>
          <input type="number" class="qmin" placeholder="Minimum Quantity"></input>
          <input type="number" class="qmax" placeholder="Maximum Quantity"></input>
          <input type="number" class="pmin" placeholder="Minimum Price"></input>
          <input type="number" class="pmax" placeholder="Maximum Price"></input>
          <button type="submit" class="search">Search</button>
          <button type="reset" class="clear">Clear Form</button>
          </center>
      </div> 
    </body>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: you need to use `<form>` tag, so reset button will know what inputs to clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Your Answer,, `input` elements are self-closed tags so `</input>` is not correct(also `link` and `meta` tags)

@iłya-bursov is right, you need a `form` to group your inputs

Or You can use js to clear all inputs when your button is clicked

```css
    body {
      background-color: #f18c8e;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 600px;
      height: 600px;
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 35px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      position: relative;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 10%;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      background-color:rgb(234, 234, 234);
    }
    
    .pid, .cid, .qmin, .qmax, .pmin, .pmax {
      width: 76%;
      font-size: 14px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      background-color: white;  
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02);
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
      margin-top: 2%;
      }
    
    .title {
      font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
      color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
      padding-top: 1em;
      font-size: 100;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    
    .subtitle {
      font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
      color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    
    .search, .clear {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 13px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      margin-top: 6%;
      padding-left: 1em;
      padding-right: 1em;
      width: 30%;
      background-color:cadetblue;
      border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02);
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .clear:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: rgb(81, 139, 141);
    }
    
    .search:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: rgb(81, 139, 141);
    }
    
    .search {
      margin-right: 45px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
    
    <html lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Contact.css"></link>
    
    <head> 
      <title>Wholesale Portal</title>
      <body>
      <div class="container">
        <form action="#">
          <center>
          <h1 class="title">Wholesale Portal</h1>
          <p class="subtitle">Please enter in values below to begin product search.</p>
          <input type="text" class="pid"  placeholder="Product Name"></input>
          <input type="text" class="cid" placeholder="Warehouse City"></input>
          <input type="number" class="qmin" placeholder="Minimum Quantity"></input>
          <input type="number" class="qmax" placeholder="Maximum Quantity"></input>
          <input type="number" class="pmin" placeholder="Minimum Price"></input>
          <input type="number" class="pmax" placeholder="Maximum Price"></input>
          <button type="submit" class="search">Search</button>
          <button type="reset" class="clear">Clear Form</button>
          </center>
        </form>
      </div> 
    </body>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Here is the js to do that

```
      <script>
          document.querySelector("[type=reset]").addEventListener('click' , ev => {
              document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( item => item.value = '')
          })
      </script>
```

you can see it's functionality here

https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiar_mansouri/4cm69e7d/2/